# Avoid sql injection from sql server itself

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have an application say query builder, which take input of sql query  from user to select some data from table

i am executing this query in sql server

Now i want to stop user to use commands other than DQl command

is it possible to do in sql server itself

Is there any command in sql server which can tell whether its DQLcommand or not, Then after i can restrict it

Thanks

Comment: You will have to be more specific? How is the SQL entered?
Can you lock down the parameters, or is it all just clear text?

You could let them connect with a different DB user, with limited rights

Comment: @M Akela: Which query!?!?

Comment: what is the input? discreet terms? or sql?

Comment: @MarcGravell its sql server query

Comment: At the point when you are letting users write SQL, this is no longer "SQL injection" - it is just "ad-hoc SQL"

Comment: @MarcGravell ; i want to know Is there any command in sql server which can tell whether its DQLcommand or not, Then after i can restrict it

Comment: @MAkela in the general case: no. The "kinda sorta ish" features for this have been deprecated and carry great big "Do not use this feature" warnings in MSDN, so I'm not going to lead you astray by mentioning them by name. But again: You can still do plenty of harm with a query.

Answer (score 1):

> its sql server query

That would be extremely hard to lock down; you can go some way using the permissions in SQL server, but it would still be easy for them to do ***very bad things*** (for example, it doesn't take very many cross joins of big tables to effectively take a server offline - or they could open a serializable transaction, select from some tables, and not close the transaction).

I would strongly suggest **don't let users write sql**. Give them other tools to do what they need.

Alternatively, run the queries on a different server - ideally where you have pushed a *safe version* of the data (i.e. without any PII) - where it doesn't matter if they dominate the server because it isn't connected to anything important. A bit like [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, usually the best practice is keep reporting db as mirror of production db (refreshed periodically from production), so reporting queries can't slow down the production. There are apps for making reports btw. - such as Microsoft Report Builder or Korzh Easy Query.